# dynamically inserted form inputs aren't posted

Tags: jquery, html, forms, dom, input

I don't usually actually ask for help, but when I do, believe me I did my research well and found nothing.

Lets make it simple, but relevant.I have a form. Part of it goes like this:

```
<div class="list-model">
    <div class="connected"><?=$items['connected']?></div>
    <div class="items"><?=$items['items']?></div>
</div>
```

When somebody clicks an `input`, i want to move it to another `div`.
I use `jQuery` for that:

```
$(".list-model").delegate(".item input", "change", function()
{
    listModel = $(this).closest(".list-model");
    item = $(this).closest(".item");
    insertTo = $(this).is(":checked") ? "connected" : "items";
    insertTo = listModel.find("."+insertTo);
    $(insertTo).append(item);
});
```

The `jQuery` works like magic, `.item` moves back and forth.

BUT

Once I "touch" the actual `input`, it won't `POST`!

It won't show in Chrome's Developer Tools under `Form Data`, nor on the server side.

Comment: show markup for `item` DOM elements and how they are located with respect to `form` tag

Answer (score 1):

Well... Of course it was my bad.

I'm using an ultra-old framework, in which the `form` element is "stuck" inside a `table` element, after `<table>` but before `<tr>`.

I took the `<form>` outside the `<table>`, so the `<form>` would wrap the `<table>` properly, and it worked just fine.

Comment: I had the exact same issue. Any idea why this is a problem if the form is inside the table element?

Comment: @Thoronwen it is just the way HTML works. There are only specific tags allowed inside `<table>`, like `<tr>`, `<th>` and so on. `<form>` isn't one of them ([Tables chapter in W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp)).